# Checking if ALL form inputs are empty with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to validate a contact form and I want to create some sort of 'form completed' message once every input field has been filled in (some of the inputs are text boxes, some are radio buttons).

Here's my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form:input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      $('.congrats').css("display", "block");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p.congrats {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<p class="congrats">Congrats!</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7huEr/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This should get you started:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form > :input").keyup(function() {
        var $emptyFields = $('.form :input').filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) === "";
        });

        if (!$emptyFields.length) {
            console.log("form has been filled");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<p class="congrats"></p>
```

Comment: Doing a `$('.form :input')` on every keyup event is not optimal. I would definitively cache that jQuery object: `var $fields = $( ':input', '.form' );`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - yeah, I though someone would point that out. Fine, I'll fix it :)

Comment: Also, of course, `$(document).ready(fn);` is history. We're doing `$(fn);` now.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Also true, but I still like the slightly more verbose and old-school version.

Comment: Would this work if the browser caches and prepopulates the values on the form?  It's looking for keyup...

Comment: This is not working for me for radio button and dropdown. I have used : var $fields = $('.profile-user-personal-form input[type="text"], .profile-user-personal-form input[type="radio"], .profile-user-personal-form select');
    $fields.keyup(function() {
        var $emptyFields = $fields.filter(function() {
            // remove the $.trim if whitespace is counted as filled
            return $.trim(this.value) === "";
        });
        if (!$emptyFields.length) {alert("form has been filled");
        } else { alert("uh-oh, you forgot to fill something out");
        }
    });

Comment: Why `$emptyFields` instead of `emptyFields`?

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```js
$("#a").on('click',function () {
var bad=0;
 $('.form :text').each(function(){ 
        if( $.trim($(this).val()) == "" ) bad++; 
            
          
    });
    
    if (bad>0) $('.congrats').css("display","block").text(bad+' missing'); 
    else $('.congrats').hide(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<p class="congrats"></p><input style="width:100px" value="check" id="a" type="button" />
```

Answer (score 5):

This one uses jQuery's `serializeArray` function, so you don't have to worry about checking different types of fields or what qualifies as an empty field:

```
$.fn.isBlank = function() {
    var fields = $(this).serializeArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].value) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};
```

Comment: To get this to work I needed to use if (fields[i].value != '')

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#check').click(function () {
    var allFilled = true;
    
    $(':input:not(:button)').each(function(index, element) {
        if (element.value === '') {
            allFilled = false;
        }
    });
    
    console.log(allFilled);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<p class="congrats"></p>
<input type="button" id="check" value="check" />
```

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7huEr/38/

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    // Iterate over each input element in the div
    $('.form input').each(function()
    {
        // Add event for when the input looses focus ( ie: was updated )
        $(this).blur( function()
        {
            // Variable if all inputs are valid
            var complete = true;

            // Iterate over each input element in div again
            $('.form input').each(function()
            {
                // If the input is not valid
                if ( !$(this).val() )
                {
                    // Set variable to not valid
                    complete = false;
                }
            });

            // If all variables are valid
            if ( complete == true )
            {
                // Show said congrats
                $('.congrats').show();
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern Vanilla Solution:

```
// Returns True if all inputs are not empty
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#myform input')).every(
    function(el){return el.value;}
)
```