# How to check if all inputs are not empty with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I need to validate a form with jQuery. I can check all my inputs one by one, but it's not a very practical solution.

How can i check if all my inputs are non-empty more efficiently? In my form i can have `input` elements of different types: text, several groups of radio, select etc.

Comment: write same class for all the fields you want to validate and then use then wirte $('.classname').val() != ''

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if ALL form inputs are empty with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517315/checking-if-all-form-inputs-are-empty-with-jquery) hope it helps and I am not the down voter `:)`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just use:

```
$("input:empty").length == 0;
```

If it's zero, none are empty.

To be a bit smarter though and also filter out items with just spaces in, you could do:

```
$("input").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
}).length == 0;
```

Comment: :empty selector will not work as intended, as it is used to select all elements that have no children.

Comment: Your filter function should be `return $.trim($(this).val()).length === 0`.

Answer (score 31):

Use `each`:

```
var isValid;
$("input").each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   if (element.val() == "") {
       isValid = false;
   }
});
```

However you probably will be better off using something like `jQuery validate` which IMO is cleaner.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud - assign isValid = true before the `each`

Comment: I think there is a problem if i have several groups of radio button.

Answer (score 15):

```
$('#form_submit_btn').click(function(){
    $('input').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).val()){
            alert('Some fields are empty');
           return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to point out my answer since I know `for` loop is faster then `$.each` loop
here it is:

just add `class="required"` to inputs you want to be required and then in jquery do:

```
$('#signup_form').submit(function(){
    var fields = $('input.required');
    for(var i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        if($(fields[i]).val() != ''){
            //whatever
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Minor point - technically, OP was asking for not empty.  This checks for empty.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        console.log('all inputs filled');
    }
    else{
        console.log('theres an empty input');
        return false
    }
});
```

you might want to wrap this in a keyup function

Answer (score 2):

You can do it.here is code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
select,textarea,input[type="text"],input[type="password"],input[type="datetime"],input[type="datetime-local"],input[type="date"],input[type="month"],input[type="time"],input[type="week"],input[type="number"],input[type="email"],input[type="url"],input[type="search"],input[type="tel"],input[type="color"],.uneditable-input{display:inline-block;height:20px;padding:4px;margin-bottom:9px;font-size:13px;line-height:18px;color:#555555;}
textarea{height:auto;}
select,textarea,input[type="text"],input[type="password"],input[type="datetime"],input[type="datetime-local"],input[type="date"],input[type="month"],input[type="time"],input[type="week"],input[type="number"],input[type="email"],input[type="url"],input[type="search"],input[type="tel"],input[type="color"],.uneditable-input{background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #cccccc;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);-webkit-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;-moz-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;-ms-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;-o-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;}textarea:focus,input[type="text"]:focus,input[type="password"]:focus,input[type="datetime"]:focus,input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,input[type="date"]:focus,input[type="month"]:focus,input[type="time"]:focus,input[type="week"]:focus,input[type="number"]:focus,input[type="email"]:focus,input[type="url"]:focus,input[type="search"]:focus,input[type="tel"]:focus,input[type="color"]:focus,.uneditable-input:focus{border-color:rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);outline:0;outline:thin dotted \9;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);height: 20px;}
select,input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{margin:3px 0;*margin-top:0;line-height:normal;cursor:pointer;}
select,input[type="submit"],input[type="reset"],input[type="button"],input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{width:auto;}
.uneditable-textarea{width:auto;height:auto;}
#country{height: 30px;}
.highlight
{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
</style>
<script>
function test()
{
var isFormValid = true;

$(".bs-example input").each(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        isFormValid = false;
        $(this).focus();
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    }
});

if (!isFormValid) { 
    alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
}

  return isFormValid;
 }  
 </script>
</head>
 <body>
 <div class="bs-example">
<form onsubmit="return test()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var isValid = true;
$("#tabledata").find("#tablebody").find("input").each(function() {
var element = $(this);
if (element.val() == "") {
isValid = false;
}
else{
isValid = true;
}
}); 
console.log(isValid);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this with Regex and Replace or with just trimming.

> **Regex example:**

```js
if ($('input').val().replace(/[\s]/, '') == '') {
    alert('Input is not filled!');
}
```

With this `replace()` function you replace white spaces with nothing (*removing white spaces*).

> **Trimming Example:**

```js
if ($('input').val().trim() == '') {
    alert('Input is not filled!');
}
```

`trim()` function removes the leading and trailing white space and line terminator characters from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if ($('input[value=""]').length > 0) {
   console.log('some fields are empty!')
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be == 0 ?

Comment: No. The query selector will select all empty fields with `input[value=""]`, and thus if any empty fields `length > 0`.

Comment: This seems to work only when the value attribute is assigned when the HTML is rendered.  In other words, if the value is initially empty and the user then enters something the selector will still include the field that was initially empty since the value attribute in the HTML doesn't get updated from input.

Answer (score -2):

let timer
$('input').on('input change', function () {
$('input').each(function () {
clearTimeout(timer)
timer = setTimeout(() => {
if ($(this).val() != '') {
console.log('all inputs filled');
} else {
console.log('theres an empty input');
return false
}
}, 0)
})
})

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.