# Jquery - How to check if all inputs in a div are not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Looking for a simple way to validate all required inputs, in a certain div.
In other words make sure all required inputs within a certain div are not empty.

This following code which was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211871/how-to-check-if-all-inputs-are-not-empty-with-jquery), shows a way to check all inputs and make sure they aren't empty (including inputs with only spaces in them) on a given page.

I am trying to do the same thing. Just within a certain div and for all required inputs.

```
$("input").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
}).length == 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the same thing, but you should change the selector to target just the input's inside a given div and add `[required]` selector to select just those who have `required` attribute :

```
$("div_selector input[required]").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
}).length == 0;
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var result = $("#div_selector input[required]").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
  }).length == 0;

  console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='first' required> Required input out of the div 

<div id='div_selector'>
  <input name='second' required> Required input
  <br>
  <input name='Third'>
  <br>
  <input name='Fourth' required> Required input
</div>
<br>
<button>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple one-liner using `Array.reduce()`:

```
$(".your-div input").reduce((allFilled, input) =>
  allFilled && $.trim($(input).val()) !== "", true)
```

Comment: thank you this is a very slick way of doing it. Does this return a boolean value?

Comment: Yep! The good thing about `Array.reduce()` is you get to define what it ultimately returns. In my example, I pass in `true` as the initial result value, and in each element's callback, we also return a boolean, so the final result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will match any input be it input, select, textarea etc

```
var canSubmit = true;
$.each($('.div-in-question').find(':input'), function(element, index){
    canSubmit = canSubmit && ($(element).val() !== '');
});
// at this point canSubmit will be true or false and you can act upon it
```

Comment: if i added input[required] in the find(). This would work. Correct?